# How to hook up ultrasonic sensor pair to arduino board? (Reposted after closing)

Tags: sensor, arduino-uno

I have a pair of ultrasonic sensors, one of which is a transmitter and the other is a receiver. How do I hook them up to the Arduino board? The board is an Arduino Uno board and the sensors are aluminum encased.

HC-SR04 sensor modules and stuff don't work as I have a pipe of diameter about one inch and the transmitter needs to be on one side of the pipe and the receiver on the other side of the pipe. That is why I need to use separated sensor modules. They are at an angle and are thus about 12 cm away from each other.

Comment: Aradhya Jain - Hi, On Stack Exchange, you aren't allowed to repost the same question again; that's classed as "noise". Your previous copy of [the same question](/questions/597671) already got an answer and people trying to better understand the limited information given, via clarifications in comments. All that effort would be wasted if you restart again, hence why it isn't allowed. Please continue in your original question. Note that, in Stack Exchange terminology, "closed" isn't necessarily a final state - help members to understand your original question & it may be voted to reopen. Thanks.